# ajax/php file download not working?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, download

I am trying to force download a txt file upon clicking on a button. The content is dynamically generated and is stored in a javascript variable. The download window doesn't appear when clicking the button however the ajax call is successful. What am I doing wrong?

The php:

```
<?php
$Proof = $_REQUEST["Proof"];
$proof = stripslashes($Proof);
$file = 'savedproof.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $proof);
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

readfile($file);
?>
```

The javascript:

```
$("#save").click(function () {

    var proof = $("#main").html();
     $.ajax({ 
             type: 'POST', 
             url: 'save-to-file.php',
             data: {Proof: Proof},
             dataType: "html"

            });
}
```

Alternatively I tried using window.location.href but I couldn't pass the variable Proof to the php file.
I tried something like this:

```
window.location.href ="download.php?Proof="+Proof;
```

Although the download dialog does appear, only the beginning part of the variable Proof is in the file.
I tested both ways on firefox and chrome.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941393/how-to-pass-input-type-file-data-in-ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX request isn't working because it isn't triggering browser navigation. It's just feeding the response to Javascript, which is ignoring it. You'll probably need to construct a fake `<form>` element and submit it to get the results to download.

As far as `window.location.href` is concerned, URLs are typically limited to about 2 to 4 KB, so you're getting cut off. So that won't work.

Comment: Do you know where can I find an example of such implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen one, actually. I'm going on guesswork here.

Comment: I used a hidden input field with name="Proof" and value=Proof and action="download.php". I submitted using jQuery and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Javascript can't download files to the client machine due to security concerns.

Just make the button a link (styled however you want) and do this:

```
<a id="save" href='/path/to/download.php' target="_blank"></a>
```

Then have an onready function to change the `href` based on the the value of `#main`

```
$.ready(
   var proof = $('#main').html();
   var href = $('#save').attr('href') + '?Proof=' + encodeURIComponent(proof);
   $('#save').attr('href', $href); 
});
```

No reason for AJAX at all here as far as I can tell.

Comment: I tried your code but for some reason the file for download is empty. Any idea why? I did alert(proof) to  make sure it has content and it does. And my php file is the same as the one above.

Comment: Sorry I typoed and had `#` in the id name in the `<a>` I have corrected it.

Comment: I did fix that in my code and there is still a problem. The file downloads it's just empty and there is no errors in the web console. The variable proof in the javascript code is not empty, I checked it. And in the php file I have this **$Proof = $_GET["Proof"];**. is there a way to check whether the variable Proof at this stage is empty or not?

Comment: Is there a limit on the size of the string proof? because when I write down on my browser's url input : .../download-to-file.php?Proof="test" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating and sending form via jquery (page not reloaded):

```
$(document).on('click', '#save', function () {
    var proof = $("#main").html();
    var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    form.attr('action', 'save-to-file.php');
    form.attr('method', 'POST');
    var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Proof').val(proof);
    form.append(input);
    form.appendTo(document.body);
    form.submit();
    form.remove();
});
```