# I want to upload file my file

Tags: php, html

I was getting undefined file as an error in my php while uploading a file.

```
function click_submit_form() {
    var action = "jb_data_charity_submit.php";
    // alert("I step"+$('#id_frm_per_details, #id_frm_acc_details , #id_frm_charity_details').serialize());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jb_data_charity_submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#id_frm_charity_details').serialize(),
        success: function (data_in) {
            //alert(data_in);
            if (data_in != null && !isEmpty(data_in) && (data_in).indexOf('VALIDATION_ERROR') != -1) {
                var value = data_in.substr(data_in.indexOf('VALIDATION_ERROR'), data_in.indexOf('|#END#'));
                var array_str = value.split('|')

                //alert(array_str[0]);
                //alert(array_str[1]);
                //alert(array_str[2]);

                var id_val = "#id_" + array_str[1].trim();
                show_error(id_val, array_str[2])
            } else {
                window.location.replace('jb_charity_regn_confirm.html');
                alert(data_in);
                // alert("FINAL");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}

<form class='form-vertical' id='id_frm_charity_details' name='frm_charity_details' action='jb_data_harity_submit.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input id="id_file" name="file" class="input-file" type="file"> <a onclick='click_submit_form();' href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-custom8 btn-large  "><i class=" icon-play"></i> Submit Application</a>
</form>
```

In my php

```
<?php

$files = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$files_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$copy = copy($files_tmp, $files);
//echo $_POST['file'];
move_uploaded_file($files_tmp, "C:\wamp32\www\jb_from_live\src\uploaded_files/" . $files);
?>
```

If i use the above line then it says undefined index 'file'.But the execution not going after  `$files=$_FILES['file']['name'];`
It says undefined index file.

Comment: please post complete code, the php part specially.

Comment: please add complete code... ad refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Post your html part as well..

Comment: try to print the $_files by `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag..may be you forget to add this in your form tag

Comment: @vaibhavmande I posted entire code.

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 I posted entire code.

Comment: @user2885199 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization

I think this may help you.

Comment: are you test my code @user2885199

Comment: @NathanSrivi yeah i have tested but it showing same undefined file ..Do i have to change anything in my php file?

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 Can you show me how to use your answer in my code.can you help me please/

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Make sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.</strike>

You cannot upload a file via ajax that simply unfortunately, for security reasons js doesn't have access to file data and therefore cannot post it via the form serialize function.

If you want to validate other parts of the form and then submit you could write a function like this

```
function submit(){
    var valid = true;
    //TODO: check validation on form, set valid to false if incorrect
    if( valid )
        document.forms[0].submit();
    return false;
}
```

If you want to use HTML5 have a geez at this answer which utilizes the FormData() function:

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Otherwise if you with to upload a file asynchronously you'll have to look for a jsp or flash fallback plugin.
Here's a really good one:
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I used that one friend

Answer (score 0):

Send image to this format

```
$('#form').submit(function() {

    var img=$('#image').val();

    var forms=($(this).serialize());


           $.ajax({
          type:"POST",          
          url: "do.php?do=upload",
          data:forms+'&r='+encodeURIComponent(img),
          success: function(result){ //your code } 


                  });
```

Try this in your code like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function click_submit_form(){

    var action = "jb_data_charity_submit.php";
               // alert("I step"+$('#id_frm_per_details, #id_frm_acc_details , #id_frm_charity_details').serialize());
    var img=$('#id_file').val();

    var forms=($('#id_frm_charity_details').serialize());

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'jb_data_charity_submit.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:forms+'&r='+encodeURIComponent(img),
                   // data: $('#id_frm_charity_details').serialize(),
                    success: function(data_in) {
                        //alert(data_in);
                        if (data_in != null && !isEmpty(data_in) && (data_in).indexOf('VALIDATION_ERROR') != -1) {


                            var value = data_in.substr(data_in.indexOf('VALIDATION_ERROR'), data_in.indexOf('|#END#'));
                            var array_str = value.split('|')


                            //alert(array_str[0]);
                            //alert(array_str[1]);
                            //alert(array_str[2]);

                            var id_val = "#id_" + array_str[1].trim();
                            show_error(id_val, array_str[2])
                        } else {



                            window.location.replace('jb_charity_regn_confirm.html');
                             alert(data_in);
                            // alert("FINAL");
                        }
                    }
                });


                return false;


            }
            </script>
 <form class='form-vertical' id='id_frm_charity_details' name='frm_charity_details' action='jb_data_harity_submit.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' >

<input id="id_file" name="file"  class="input-file" type="file">
 <a onclick='click_submit_form();' href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-custom8 btn-large  "><i class=" icon-play"></i> Submit Application</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks man but it is showing the same error...Do i have to change anything in my php file?

Comment: Where you got undefined in your js or php??

Comment: I'm  getting it from php

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `FormData` instead of `serialize()`. The advantage of using `formData` is that you can also upload pdf,xml,JSON files by specifying their content-type.

For eg:

```
var fData = new FormData();
fData.append("XML",  new Blob([ xml ], { type: "text/xml" });
fData.append("JSON", new Blob([ JSON.stringify(json) ], { type: "application/json" }));
fData.append("PDF",  file);
```

Comment: Can you show me how to use your answer in my code.can you help me please?

Comment: Check this link. And proceed according to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941393/how-to-pass-input-type-file-data-in-ajax-call