# Gathering file upload data for AJAX submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have searched some other questions but none I can find use the same method of gathering form data that I do.

I am gathering the values from the form via jQuery and adding them to a javascript object, then posting this information via AJAX with jQuery. All works fine:

```
$("#contact-form-id").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   // validation stuff here
   // ...
   postForm(); // running the postForm() function if validation successful
});

function postForm(){
    var userName = $('input[name="user-name"]').val();
    var userEmail = $('input[name="user-email"]').val();
    var userPhone = $('input[name="user-phone"]').val();
    var userMessage = $('textarea[name="user-other-info"]').val();

    var valuesToPost = {
        userName: userName,
        userEmail: userEmail,
        userPhone: userPhone,
        userMessage: userMessage
    };

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/actions/post-contact-form.php",
         data: {data : valuesToPost},
         cache: false,
         success: function(){
             // success!
         }
     });
};
```

As you can see, I am using `preventDefault` to prevent the form submitting and am then validating it before gathering all the data into my object `valuesToPost`

But there is one last field I am currently ignoring, and that is a file upload field.

My understanding is that when files are uploaded they are held in a temporary directory until the script has finished executing? I believe I can collect the location path for the temp file 'on the other side' (PHP script). But I don't know how to *gather the file value/input from the upload* nor do I know how to send this along with my object `valuesToPost`

I guess this is what I'm imagining:

```
var fileUpload = /* what goes here? how do I store the file upload in a variable in jQuery? */

        var valuesToPost = {
            userName: userName,
            userEmail: userEmail,
            userPhone: userPhone,
            userMessage: userMessage,
            fileUpload: fileUpload
        };
```

Am I completely wrong? I was hoping I'd be able to get the path of the temp URL from the file upload, add it to my object, and then download the file in my PHP script (to be attached to an email).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to store submitted data, including uploaded file

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

**$(this)** points to the submitted form!

Then in the ajax request set:

```
data: formData
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: I really hate seeing `$(this)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment just yet to find out more, but this sounds like what you are trying to do:

[Passing input files ajax & jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941393/how-to-pass-input-type-file-data-in-ajax-call)

The second two answers are worth mention.

Essentially though the var you are looking for is

```
var fileUpload = $('input[name="user-file"]')[0].files[0]);
```

Hope that helps.